# PHP Authentication System to Replace PHPBB

Tags: php, mysql, authentication, phpbb

I currently use phpBB to authenticate users to pages outside of their bulletin board system.  I have found that I really do not need the phpbb forums any longer and would like to totally gut phpbb and replace it with a new authentication system (maybe write my own).

After doing some research, I have found that phpbb no longer md5 hashes their passwords and now does some type of custom hashing algorithm.  My question is two fold:

1. What is the best way to extract passwords (10,000+ users) from the phpbb databases for import in to a new system that can read the existing passwords.  If this is not possible what is the best way to go about having users authenticate?
2. Is there a good php authentication system that I should be using or should I just write my own?  My only two requirements are Facebook connect and being able to use my existing username and password list.  I have read this tutorial which appears pretty intuitive http://www.wikihow.com/Create-a-Secure-Login-Script-in-PHP-and-MySQL

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Create Database -> Connect to Database -> Create Login Page -> Forward the post to the check page -> check if user exists -> If User Exists check if password matches -> If password matches assign to a new session -> Constantly check that session for if it's set

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**One**. PHPBB stores an encryption "salt" that is used to hash the passwords, find the salt and you can use it in your new app, or use it to loop through your passwords and create new passwords using a different encryption when you write your own system if you like.

You can see how the salt is created and checked in the **phpbbHash.php** file.

**Two**. If you don't fancy using a [PHP framework](http://www.phpframeworks.com/) to take care of all this for you, then yes maybe write your own - The tutorial you listed is quite good.. loads on Google.. [this one](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/a-better-login-system/) is quite a good ACL focused tutorial.

Comment: You have linked to a tutorial using the depreciated `mysql_*` functions, they should not be used. Use alternatives like MySQLI or PDO

Comment: Yes that tutorial was written in 2009 though has been updated a little since though. It is intended to act as a guide, as are all tutorials.. rather than a set in stone way of doing things.

Comment: With someone who might know zilch in terms of Login & Authentication methods, they could take this as a stepping stone towards the `mysql` functions. Completely understandable in terms of why you linked it; But could specify in your answer that its a guide and the OP should look into other Database API instead of the `mysql_*` functions

Comment: I did some more research and it does not appear there is a phpbbHash.php file (at least I cannot find it in the latest version of phpbb) - also it doesn't appear phpbb uses a salt, it leverages phpass http://www.openwall.com/phpass/